# Having a long running service in its own task for networking

Tags: android, multithreading

so my intentions is the following:
I need a background service that mainly takes send requests (UDP) from the main UI and waits for its responses which in turn are dispatched back to the main UI. This is a pretty synchronous process. But additionally, I want the Service to wait for asynchronous messages that can be received any time over the network, for example a network client wants to notify me or to report an error.
What would be the best way to implement this? 
Well for IPC the Messenger class could be useful to handle data. 
Could it be implemented like the "Remote Messenger Service Sample" found here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html ??

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project, i have a service that is permanently running.

I have also 3 threads created in this service, so all in background. Each one of them does some work, requesting http data also: i've done it with the Handler, managing the message queue.

It's easy and grows well, growing the dimension and complexity of project.

So, yes, i should follow that way.

P.S.: If you have to do work in background, remember to acquire wake_locks with PowerManager, ensuring you that CPU will stay on when phone goes in standby (it tooked me some days to understand why threads stop to work when phone goes in standby).

In the main thread, i declared the 4 handlers (2 for two-side communication with recordingThread, and 2 for two-side communication with sendingThread):
Then simply create the other 2 threads; look at Looper calls: it's needed to do not let your thread to die when the code is executed, and to wait for incoming messages coming on handlers created inside its own execution (in this case inside the run() method).
I've also declared a private class for each handler associated to a thread: this way every thread has its own channel to communicate with different 'action' to do (the switch cases).
There's also the other handler, the recordingThread handler, not shown here; but the idea is the same:

```
private Handler m_recordingThreadHandler, m_sendingThreadHandler,
            m_thisRecordingThreadhandler, m_thisSendingThreadHandler;


public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        m_thisRecordingThreadhandler = new UpdRecHandler();
        m_recordingThread = new RecordingThread(m_mainThreadContext,
                m_thisRecordingThreadhandler, m_configuration, m_picturesDir);
        m_recordingThread.setName("recordingThread");
        m_recordingThread.start();

        m_thisSendingThreadHandler = new UpdSenHandler();
        m_sendingThread = new SendingThread(m_mainThreadContext,
                m_thisSendingThreadHandler, m_configuration);
        m_sendingThread.setName("sendingThread");
        m_sendingThread.start();

        Looper.loop();

    }

private class UpdRecHandler extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Message m;

            switch (msg.what) {

            case Utils.SEND_THIS_THREAD_HANDLER:
                Log.i(TAG, "Ricevuto Handler di recordingThread.");

                m_recordingThreadHandler = (Handler) msg.obj;
                m_recordingThreadReady = true;
                checkForAllThreadsReady();

                break;

            case Utils.FORCE_RESET:
                Log.i(TAG,
                        "RecordingThread ha compeltato la procedura per il reset.");
                m_recordingThreadResetted = true;
                checkForThreadsResetted();
                break;
...more cases...
}
```

This code is instead from recordingThread class.
Once created, the run method is executed, in which i pass to the main thread (the code previously seen) the handler of this thread, created in this run() method: in this way i enable 2-sided communication.
Again, in the recordingThread i create a private class for the handler. And again i've put the Looper calls to let thread be alive once run method is executed.

```
public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        Log.i(TAG, "In esecuzione, mando il mio handler a updateThread");

        m_thisThreadHandler = new RecUpdHandler();
        m_mainThreadHandler.obtainMessage(Utils.SEND_THIS_THREAD_HANDLER,
                m_thisThreadHandler).sendToTarget();

        Looper.loop();
    }



private class RecUpdHandler extends Handler {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Message m;

            switch (msg.what) {

            case Utils.TAKE_PHOTO:
                ...do work....
                break;
               case Utils.UPDATE_CONFIGURATION:
                ... do other work...
                break;

}
```

If you want to let your thread terminate, you have simply to kill the Looper associated to that thread, doing as follow:

```
Looper.myLooper().quit();
```

And remember that an handler is associated automatically to the thread in which it's created: if handler A is created in thread T1, then you can pass a reference of A to T2 and T3. Those thread are then capable of send messages to T1, but not viceversa.
That's because i've created 4 handlers, for enabling 2-side communication.

Comment: Thx so far. If you have any coded examples let me know.  Ok, so if the phone goes in standby I assume the user does not care about data received. When I resume from standby does the thread resume as well? I mean, the thread does not get destroyed, right?

Comment: Yes, thread will be resumed when phone wake up from standby.
Posting some code snippets in a while...